# Creating Transparent Water Droplets in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been working on a project where I need to add some transparent water droplets on a bottle but they render completely white. I have tried using many different shaders to achieve this effect but nothing has worked so far.

I have tried adding a glass shader, I have tried using a transparent shader, I have tried using a refraction shader, and I have tried using a combination of these.

I am starting to wonder if it has to do with my lighting, I am just using a basic 3-point lighting system.

I would really appreciate any help that is given.

Comment: Andrew price has a tutorial on blenderguru on water droplets http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/how-to-make-a-rainy-window/

Answer (score 2):

### **Glass Shader**

The Glass Shader (Glass BSDF) with it's default settings is a very good shader for water droplets in Cycles:

[image]

You will need to upload your blend file in order for me to determine exactly what is causing yours to be white. Uploading to [PasteAll](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) is very convenient and easy: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/