# How to add shadows for transparent materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

How to remove the darkness of water droplets, By adding receive transparent to  "soft drink can" material resulting in a more natural looking 
 water droplets, adding Fresnel etc.?

[image: Coke can with condensation]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/creating-transparent-water-droplets-in-cycles http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/rendering-a-water-drop-in-cycles

Comment: You should get a decent effect with default glass material and multiple importance sampling enabled for your lights

Comment: That render looks very grainy, increase the samples in the render panel.

Comment: Also, you should include an image of your material setup for the droplets.

Comment: These are the materials for water and can label http://imgur.com/rIJzjLR http://imgur.com/IhCp4x4 respectively sorry for delay was out of station